# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't generate .lib file for a dll project

Tags: c++, dll

I create dll project in visual studio 2019.

I wanna export my Array class to dll.

Here is the code :

```
//ArrayLib.h
#pragma once

#ifdef ARRAY_EXPORTS
#define ARRAY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ARRAY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef signed long int Long;
template <typename T>

class ARRAY_API Array {
public:
    Array(Long capacity = 256);
    Array(const Array& source);
    ~Array();
    Long Store(Long index, T object);
    Long Insert(Long index, T object);
    Long AppendFromFront(T object);
    Long AppendFromRear(T object);
    Long Delete(Long index);
    Long DeleteFromFront();
    Long DeleteFromRear();
    void Clear();
    Long Modify(Long index, T object);
    Long LinearSearchUnique(void *key, int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void LinearSearchDuplicate(void *key, Long* (*indexes), Long *count, int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    Long BinarySearchUnique(void *key, int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void BinarySearchDuplicate(void *key, Long* (*indexes), Long *count, int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void BubbleSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void SelectionSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void InsertionSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    void Merge(const Array& one, const Array& other, int(*compare)(void*, void*));
    T& GetAt(Long index);

    T& operator [](Long index);
    T* operator +(Long index);
    Array& operator =(const Array& source);

    void Swap(Long toIndex, Long fromIndex);

    Long GetCapacity() const;
    Long GetLength() const;

private:
    T(*front);
    Long capacity;
    Long length;
};
```

```
//ArrayLib.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "ArrayLib.h"


template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::GetCapacity() const {
    return this->capacity;
}
template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::GetLength() const {
    return this->length;
}

//함수 정의
template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(Long capacity) {
    this->front = new T[capacity];
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->length = 0;
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array& source) {
    this->front = new T[source.capacity];
    this->capacity = source.capacity;
    Long i = 0;
    while (i < source.length) {
        this->front[i] = source.front[i];
        i++;
    }
    this->length = source.length;
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array() {
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::Store(Long index, T object) {
    this->front[index] = object;
    this->length++;

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::Insert(Long index, T object) {
    T(*objects);
    Long i;
    Long j = 0;

    objects = new T[this->capacity + 1];
    i = 0;
    while (i < index) {
        objects[j] = this->front[i];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    j++;
    while (i < this->length) {
        objects[j] = this->front[i];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }
    this->front = objects;
    this->capacity++;
    this->front[index] = object;
    this->length++;

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::AppendFromFront(T object) {
    Long index = 0;
    T(*objects);
    Long i = 0;
    objects = new T[this->capacity + 1];
    while (i < this->length) {
        objects[i + 1] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }

    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }

    this->front = objects;
    this->capacity++;
    this->front[index] = object;
    this->length++;

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::AppendFromRear(T object) {
    Long index;
    T(*objects);
    Long i = 0;
    objects = new T[this->capacity + 1];
    while (i < this->length) {
        objects[i] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }
    this->front = objects;
    this->capacity++;
    index = this->capacity - 1;
    this->front[index] = object;
    this->length++;

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::Delete(Long index) {
    T(*objects) = 0;
    Long i = 0;
    if (this->capacity > 1) {
        objects = new T[this->capacity - 1];
    }
    while (i < index) {
        objects[i] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }
    i = index + 1;
    while (i < this->length) {
        objects[i - 1] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
        this->front = 0;
    }
    if (this->capacity > 1) {
        this->front = objects;
    }

    this->capacity--;
    this->length--;
    index = -1;

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
Long Array<T>::DeleteFromFront() {
    T(*objects) = 0;
    Long i = 1;
    if (this->capacity > 1) {
        objects = new T[this->capacity - 1];
    }
    while (i < this->length) {
        objects[i - 1] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
        this->front = 0;
    }

    if (this->capacity > 1) {
        this->front = objects;
    }
    this->capacity--;
    this->length--;
    return -1;
}

template<typename T>
Long Array<T>::DeleteFromRear()
{
    T(*objects) = 0;
    Long i = 0;

    if (this->capacity > 1)
    {
        objects = new T[this->capacity - 1];
    }

    while (i < this->length - 1)
    {
        objects[i] = this->front[i];
        i++;
    }

    if (this->capacity > 1)
    {
        this->front = objects;
    }

    this->capacity--;
    this->length--;

    return -1;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::Clear()
{
    if (this->front != 0)
    {
        delete[] this->front;
        this->front = 0;
    }

    this->capacity = 0;
    this->length = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Long Array<T>::Modify(Long index, T object)
{
    this->front[index] = object;

    return index;
}

template<typename T>
Long Array<T>::LinearSearchUnique(void *key, int(*compare)(void*, void*))
{
    Long index = -1;
    Long i = 0;

    while (i < this->length && compare(this->front + i, key) != 0)
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (i < this->length)
    {
        index = i;
    }

    return index;
}

template<typename T>
void Array<T>::LinearSearchDuplicate(void *key, Long *(*indexes), Long *count, int(*compare)(void*, void*))
{
    Long i = 0;
    Long j = 0;
    *count = 0;

    *indexes = new Long[this->length];

    while (i < this->length)
    {
        if (compare(this->front + i, key) == 0)
        {
            (*indexes)[j] = i;
            j++;
            (*count)++;
        }

        i++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
Long Array<T>::BinarySearchUnique(void *key, int(*compare)(void*, void*))
{
    Long index = -1;
    Long first = 0;
    Long last;
    Long mid;

    last = this->length - 1;
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    while (first <= last && compare(this->front + mid, key) != 0)
    {
        if (compare(this->front + mid, key) < 0)
        {
            first = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            last = mid - 1;
        }

        mid = (first + last) / 2;
    }

    if (first <= last)
    {
        index = mid;
    }

    return index;
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::BinarySearchDuplicate(void *key, Long* (*indexes), Long *count, int(*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    Long first = 0;
    Long last;
    Long mid;
    Long i;
    Long j = 0;
    *count = 0;

    *indexes = new Long[this->length];
    last = this->length - 1;
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    while (first <= last && compare(this->front + mid, key) != 0) {
        if (compare(this->front + mid, key) < 0) {
            first = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            last = mid - 1;
        }
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    i = mid - 1;
    while (i >= first && compare(this->front + i, key) == 0) {
        i--;
    }
    first = i + 1;
    i = first;
    while (i <= last && compare(this->front + i, key) == 0) {
        (*indexes)[j] = i;
        j++;
        (*count)++;
        i++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::BubbleSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    Long i = 0;
    Long j;
    T temp;
    Long check = 1;

    while (i < this->length - 1 && check == 1) {
        check = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (j < this->length - i - 1) {
            if (compare(this->front + j, this->front + (j + 1)) > 0) {
                temp = this->front[j];
                this->front[j] = this->front[j + 1];
                this->front[j + 1] = temp;
                check = 1;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::SelectionSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    Long i = 0;
    Long j;
    T min;
    Long minIndex;

    while (i < this->length - 1) {
        minIndex = i;
        min = this->front[minIndex];
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < this->length) {
            if (compare(&min, this->front + j) > 0) {
                minIndex = j;
                min = this->front[minIndex];
            }
            j++;
        }
        this->front[minIndex] = this->front[i];
        this->front[i] = min;
        i++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::InsertionSort(int(*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    Long i = 1;
    Long j;
    T temp;

    while (i < this->length) {
        temp = this->front[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && compare(this->front + j, &temp) > 0) {
            this->front[j + 1] = this->front[j];
            j--;
        }
        this->front[j + 1] = temp;
        i++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::Merge(const Array& one, const Array& other, int(*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    Long i = 0;
    Long j = 0;
    Long k = 0;

    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }
    this->front = new T[one.length + other.length];
    this->capacity = one.length + other.length;
    this->length = 0;
    while (i < one.length && j < other.length) {
        if (compare(one.front + i, other.front + j) < 0) {
            this->front[k] = one.front[i];
            k++;
            this->length++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            this->front[k] = other.front[j];
            k++;
            this->length++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < one.length) {
        this->front[k] = one.front[i];
        k++;
        this->length++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < other.length) {
        this->front[k] = other.front[j];
        k++;
        this->length++;
        j++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& Array<T>::GetAt(Long index) {
    return this->front[index];
}

template <typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator [](Long index) {
    return this->front[index];
}

template <typename T>
T* Array<T>::operator +(Long index) {
    return (this->front + index);
}

template <typename T>
Array<T>& Array<T>::operator =(const Array& source) {
    if (this->front != 0) {
        delete[] this->front;
    }
    this->front = new T[source.capacity];
    this->capacity = source.capacity;
    Long i = 0;
    while (i < source.length) {
        this->front[i] = source.front[i];
        i++;
    }
    this->length = source.length;

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void Array<T>::Swap(Long toIndex, Long fromIndex) {
    T object = this->front[fromIndex];
    Long count;
    if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
        count = fromIndex - toIndex;
        memmove(this->front + toIndex + 1, this->front + toIndex, sizeof(T) * count);
    }
    else {
        count = toIndex - fromIndex;
        memmove(this->front + fromIndex, this->front + fromIndex + 1, sizeof(T) * count);
    }
    this->front[toIndex] = object;

}
```

When i build the project, the output is :

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ArrayLib, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>pch.cpp

1>ArrayLib.cpp

1>dllmain.cpp

1>Generating Code...

1>ArrayLib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\kch79\source\repos\ArrayLib\Debug\ARRAYLIB.dll

========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

According to MSDN document, the output should be this :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MathLibrary, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>pch.cpp
1>dllmain.cpp
1>MathLibrary.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>   Creating library C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\MathLibrary\Debug\MathLibrary.lib and object C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\MathLibrary\Debug\MathLibrary.exp
1>MathLibrary.vcxproj -> C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\MathLibrary\Debug\MathLibrary.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There should be three components in order to make a dynamic library work, namely a header file, a LIB file, and a DLL file.

But my dll project doesn't create lib file.

Is there any mistake from my code?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your class cannot be exported because it is template, so you just didn't export anything and that's why lib file was not produced. Templates cannot be exported because they are used only in compile-time. You may export Array, but not Array.
For example try to do this:

```
Array<Long>* ARRAY_API CreateArrayLong(Long capacity) {
  return new Array<Long>(capacity);
}

Array<double>* ARRAY_API CreateArrayDouble(Long capacity) {
  return new Array<double>(capacity);
}

...
```

and you will see generated lib file. Also you need to provide your header file which contains Array with DLL